# How to keep listening to the connected TCP sockets by "select"

Tags: python, sockets, select, tcp

All my clients sockets do the same thing: send a package every second(22 bytes)

Server code as below:

```
import select
import socket
import datetime
SList = []


class Tserver:

    def __init__(self, portNum):
        host = '127.0.0.1'
        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.server.bind((host, portNum))
        self.server.listen(1)


def GETPACK():
    # function for CRC check
    def CRC(DATA_STR):
        return 1

    # generate 100 sockets to listen
    for x in range(100):
        SList.append(Tserver(x+10000))

    inputs = []
    # put in inputs
    for x in range(100):
        inputs.append(SList[x].server)

    while(True):
        ready_socks, _, _ = select.select(inputs, [], [])
        for sock in ready_socks:
            c, addr = sock.accept()
            while(True):
                data = c.recv(22)
                if len(data) == 22:  # To make sure the data-length is 22
                    # Turn the pack string into bytearray
                    data_bytes = bytearray()
                    data_bytes.extend(data)
                    if CRC(data_bytes) == 1:
                        print "Connected from client IP Address:" + str(addr)
                        # ID
                        ID = 256*data_bytes[1] + data_bytes[2]
                        print "ID: ", ID
                        now = datetime.datetime.now()
                        print "now: ", str(now)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    GETPACK()
```

My server can only print the packages sent by the first connected socket.
And my question is how to print out all message from each ports whenever a package is sent to the server.

Comment: Did you try to debug your code?

Comment: Sockets just don't work this way. You should re-read the socket documentation I believe. You only create one socket to listen on a port, then `accept` will return a newly created socket for each connection.

Comment: @peterh Not really, and I'm still working on it. Need some good advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this PyMOTW entry](https://pymotw.com/2/select/) for a detailed explanation of how to use the `select` module to write a select-based server.

The main differences between that example and your code are:

You just create one listening socket - `server`. There is no need to listen on multiple ports.

The variable `inputs` will be a list consisting of `server` and any other open socket connections to clients.

Your service loop will look like:

```
while true:
  readable, _, _ = select.select(inputs, [], [])
  for r in readable:
    if r is server:
      # handle a new incoming connection
      # this will add an entry to the variable inputs
    else:
      # read some data from socket r and process it
```

When you attempt to read from a client socket and get an EOF condition, you can close that socket and remove it from the `inputs` variable.

Answer (score 0):

@ErikR  Thanks for your help, i changed my code, and it worked fine.

The reason that my code doesn't work was because of two things:

1.I only create one connection to recv data from my clients.

2.The same connection can't be accepted again for recv, if the clients does't reconnect.(my code doesn't check the exception when clients shutdown)

Code as below:

```
import select, socket, datetime
SList = []
SconnList = []

class Tserver:
    def __init__(self, portNum):
        host = '127.0.0.1'
        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
        self.server.bind((host,portNum))
        self.server.listen(1)
        print "Server ports: "+str(portNum)

class Sconn:
    def __init__(self, sock):
        self.conn, self.addr = sock.accept()        

def GETPACK():
    # function for CRC check
    def CRC(DATA_STR):
        return 1

    # generate 100 sockets to listen        
    for x in range(100):
        SList.append(Tserver(x+10000))

    inputs = []
    # put in inputs
    for x in range(100):
        inputs.append(SList[x].server)

    while(True):
        ready_socks,_,_ = select.select(inputs, [], [])
        for sock in ready_socks:
            try:
                SconnList.append(Sconn(sock))
                SconnList.reverse()
                inputs.append(SconnList[0].conn)
            except:     
                data = sock.recv(22)
                if len(data) == 22: # To make sure the data-length is 22
                #Turn the pack string into bytearray
                    data_bytes = bytearray()
                    data_bytes.extend(data)
                    if CRC(data_bytes) == 1:
                        print "IP Address:" + str(sock.getsockname())
                        #ID
                        ID = 256*data_bytes[1] + data_bytes[2]
                        print "ID: ",ID
                        now =  datetime.datetime.now()
                        print "now: ",str(now)
                        print ""
                        print ""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    GETPACK()
```